# How to get properties of Loggedin user in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, request, nestjs

I am able to get the current logged in user object in the service.ts with this `const loggedin = this.request.user`

```
export class PostService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request,
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

async GetPosts(){
     const loggedin = this.request.user
        loggedin.firstname;
}
}
```

But I cant access the properites of the current user

I tried `loggedin.firstname` but I got `Property 'firstname' does not exist on type 'User'`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the issue,

```
export class PostService {
    constructor(
        @Inject(REQUEST) private request: any,
        private userService: UserService
    ) { }

async GetPosts(){
     const loggedin = this.request.user

}
}
```

I changed the request type to `any` and I destructure it like this

```
  const { _id, firstname } = this.request.user
```